# How to mark multiple good acceptable answers?

Tags: feature-request

I often find that when I ask a question, I receive multiple answers that are equally well. However, the system only lets you mark a single question as "answered." Is there any way around this, or should I just pick one, or pick none?

I hate to award someone with the "correct" answer when another person has an equally correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"accepted" is only meant to imply "this worked for me." It does not mean "this answer is correct." (The most correct answer is probably the one with the most up-votes. Probably. :^)

If you truly feel two (or more) answers are identically useful to you, you'll just have to make the decision on some other basis. Perhaps: Choose the answer written first. Or choose the one from the newest user, (giving them 15 points and a warm-fuzzy early in their community participation.)

Comment: I think you're right about going back and marking the answer with the most upvotes as the correct one if multiple good answers exist.

Comment: IMO, too often upvotes are as much an indicator of the author's popularity, as they are of an answer being more correct.

Comment: @MikePennington upvotes in opposed comment threads where users are disagreeing on something can also be used as a way of 'taking sides' rather than marking the comment as useful. The purpose of up and downvotes is becoming a bit blurry.